# Parallel Port PCIe card does not show as /dev/parport and does not work

Tags: ubuntu, pop-os, pci

I have a PCIe ParallelPort controller which sadly does not want to work. After plugging the parallel port card, it does not show up as I was expecting as `/dev/parport0`. Doing:

```
sudo rmmod parport_pc
sudo modprobe parport_pc io=0x4000
```

does show `/dev/parport0` but the card does not work. When sending values on the data pin, I don't get any voltage. And `dmesg | grep parport` shows:

```
scheltie@linux-mathieu:~$ sudo dmesg | grep parport
[  266.761700] parport 0x4000 (WARNING): CTR: wrote 0x0c, read 0xff
[  266.761705] parport 0x4000 (WARNING): DATA: wrote 0xaa, read 0xff
[  266.761705] parport 0x4000: You gave this address, but there is probably no parallel port there!
[  266.761719] parport0: PC-style at 0x4000, irq 0 [PCSPP,TRISTATE]
```

Output from `sudo lspci -v`:

```
0000:01:00.2 Parallel controller: Asix Electronics Corporation AX99100 PCIe to Multi I/O Controller (prog-if 03 [IEEE1284])
    Subsystem: Asix Electronics Corporation (Wrong ID) Parallel Port
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    I/O ports at 4008 [disabled] [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4000 [disabled] [size=8]
    Memory at 74001000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Memory at 74000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
```

What strikes me is the `[disabled]` marked after the I/O ports and memory address.
Any idea as to what might be the issue and how I could fix it?

Running on POP_OS 22.04 LTS, up-to-date.
On a dual-boot computer with Windows, the card does work on Windows. Thus it is enabled in the BIOS.

Comment: Found this rejected patch, perhaps... : https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220806113124.608017725@osadl.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with a [StarTech PEX1P2](https://www.startech.com/en-us/cards-adapters/pex1p2) PCIe parallel port. `lspci -nnv` said that the I/O ports were disabled:

```
06:00.2 Parallel controller [0701]: Asix Electronics Corporation AX99100 PCIe to Multi I/O Controller [125b:9100] (prog-if 03 [IEEE1284])
        Subsystem: Asix Electronics Corporation (Wrong ID) Parallel Port [a000:2000]
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 5
        I/O ports at e010 [disabled] [size=8]
        I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=8]
        Memory at fcc01000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
        Memory at fcc00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
```

I solved it by creating `/etc/modprobe.d/parport_pc.conf` with the following:

```
install parport_pc setpci -d 125b:9100 command=101; /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install parport_pc
options parport_pc io=0xe010 irq=auto
```

Be sure to replace `125b:9100` with the device ID from the first line of `lspci -nnv` and replace `0xe010` with the I/O port from the fourth line. Now when the `parport_pc` module is loaded (e.g. with `sudo modprobe parport_pc`), it will set up the I/O ports at the same time.

There are two key parts here: The `setpci` command enables the I/O ports and the `options` line tells the driver what the base I/O address is. See the [Linux Serial HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-8.html#pci_enabled) for an explanation of `setpci` and [this Arch Linux form post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=22893) for an explanation of modprobe.d's `install` command.